# How to accept message only from authenticated user

Tags: authentication, exim

I want exim to accept messages only from that user which authorized via SMTP. Now I have these lines in the config:

```
  accept
    authenticated = *
    sender_domains = +local_domains
    control = submission/sender_retain
    control = dkim_disable_verify

  deny
    message = Unauthorized
    sender_domains = +local_domains
    !authenticated = *
```

It makes that any authorized user can send messages from local domains. For example, I have two domains: local1.com and local2.com and users user1 and user2 (suggest that both of domains have these users). If I authenticate as user1@local1.com I can MAIL FROM: user2@local1.com and even user2@local2.com. But I want to deny any different users even if they are local. Only user1@local1.com must be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

During authentication user's credentials are stored in the `$auth1`, `$auth2` and `$auth3` variables. More specifically, `$auth1` contains user's login in form localpart@domain.tld. So you have just verify whether that login is equal to the `$sender_address`:

```
accept
  authenticated = *
  condition     = ${if eq{$auth1}{$sender_address}}

deny
  authenticated = *
```

Comment: I'm not sure if auth1 is siutable for all protocols (LOGIN PLAIN CRAM_MD5). But with your help I found variable $authenticated_id. And it seems this variable is that what I look for. What your suggestions about this variable? Can I use it or $auth1 will be better?

Comment: Try to `logwrite = $authenticated_id` from ACL to ensure.